# Find out $k$ so that exactly the first $k$-th power sum of polynomial over finite field be 0

Tags: number-theory

I'm concerning about a question arising from Hermite Criterion:

For $f(x) \in F_p[x]$, compute the smallest integer $k$, s.t.
$$\sum_{x \in F_p} f^i(x) = 0 (1 \le i \le k-1)$$, and
$$\sum_{x \in F_p} f^k(x) \neq 0$$

This $k$ is invariant under substitutions of permutation polynomials, but I still have no idea specifically find out $k$ for given $p$ and $f(x)$

Is there a good way to compute $k$ for given $p$ and $f(x)$, or a good way to "explain" $k$ (with algebraic number theory or geometry)?